# How to parse a row in SQL into columns (separator-spaces)

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, parsing, row

I need to parse row (with spaces) into two different columns in SQL. The rows look like that:

**FullName**

John Mayer

Rajon Jennings

Donna Fraye

Michael Moore

So the expected result is :

**Name**

John

Rajon

Donna

Michael

**Surname**

Mayer

Jennings

Fraye

Moore

How can i do that in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a requirement like First Name should be string before first space and rest everything what follows should go as Last name , you can update two columns as:

```
Update T
Set T.FirstName =  Left(ltrim(rtrim(FullName)), CHARINDEX(' ',ltrim(rtrim(FullName))))
   ,T.LastName =   Right(ltrim(rtrim(FullName)),len(FullName)- CHARINDEX(' ',ltrim(rtrim(FullName))))
From Test T
```

[Check Demo here..](http://rextester.com/RWGD72923)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a split function.This function must be created.
Here are some examples :

http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/split-string-to-table-using-transact-sql/

[Split function by comma in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512855/split-function-by-comma-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1):

If there is only ever 1 space / 2 name and you don't have to cater for names like Vincent van Gough, then a combination of substring and charindex should do.

```
select substring(fullname, 1, charindex(' ', fullname)) as name,
       substring(fullname, charindex(' ', fullname)+1, len(fullname)-charindex(' ', fullname)) as surname
from tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not cover people with the same first and last name (ie. john john) but will work for rest. Not recommended but is a different solution.

```
select left(fullname, charindex(' ',fullname)) Name,
  replace(fullname,left(fullname, charindex(' ',fullname)),'') Surname
from names
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d9cc/5)